# один амперсанд в javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function lovefunc(flower1, flower2){
  return ((flower1 ^ flower2) & 1) == 1;
}
```

есть такой пример кода, подскажите пожалуйста что делает в данном примере один амперсанд '&' каретка '^'. гугл выдает только && (типа логические операторы). Спасибо

Comment: Это для работы с битами: `^` - xor, `&` - И. Пример: `101 ^ 110 = 011`, `101 & 110 = 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` и `^` - это побитовые (bitwise) операторы.

Побитовые операции действительно проводят вычисления над своими операндами - попарно над каждым битом из первого и второго операнда.

Логические же операции сами по себе ничего не обрабатывают, они только проверяют условия и возвращают один из операндов.

Например, логическое ИЛИ, `123 || 321`, возвращает `123`, т.к. для ИЛИ надо чтобы один из операндов был `true`, и проверки `123` на `true` достаточно для получения результата.

```js
alert(1 & 2); // 01 & 10 = 00
alert(1 ^ 2); // 01 ^ 10 = 11  (3)
alert(1 && 2); // 01 && 10 = 2 - (true)
alert(123 || 321); // 123 (true)
```

<sub>дополнено 
@AndreyBakharev  по мотивам https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops</sub>

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, посмотрел туториал, понял как он сравнивает. Подскажите пожалуйста типовую область их приминения, потому как щас не понимаю где их можно "по уму" применить. Спасибо

Comment: @IgorKalamurda такая же, как в других языках - какие-то низкоуровневые расчеты. проверки флагов (как в вашем примере). когда вам надо будет их применить - вы сразу же поймете :)